# How to automate chatbot (developed using Amazon Lambda and Lex) using Botium

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I need to do automation to test the chatbot that has been developed using **Amazon  lambda and Lex**, how can i automate the chatbot using botium or is there is any other way to automate.

Answer (score 3):

Botium is still not supporting to aws lex.

You can use aws-lex api for automate chatbot.

Lex API reference

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostText.html

Git Issue

https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core/issues/73

Comment: I want to add that as we recently got several community requests regarding Amazon Lex, we gave it higher priority now. So in 1-2 weeks, the Botium connector for Amazon Lex will be there.

Comment: @FlorianTreml Till then if there is any other way to  automate the chat box applications, please share some blog so that I can explore

Answer (score 2):

Botium now supports Amazon Lex: https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-lex